# How to add a text column to magento dropdown attribute option in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom, attribute-options

I would like to extend the options grid for a dropdown product attribute with a new text field which will appear as a new column.

In that field I'm going to store the matching ERP_ID but I would also like to have it visible on the backend here:

[image]

This is the first time I'm attempting this so I'd like to know if it's possible and how to proceed with it. Even links to study on the procedure would help a lot.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess my first approach will be check cheking the ui_compoentn form, if there is one, for that controller. Check the PHTMLs also, i mean i guess it could be some kind of a xml/phtml modification to add a new input to the form and then plugin the post controller to add it to the model, which have a new column to save that data

Comment: I've added the new column to the table for eav_attribute_option and I was planning to find the AttributeOptionRepositoryInterface for creating an afterGet, afterGetList, and afterSave Plugin but it seems AttributeOption does not have a repository interface :(

Comment: Do you happen to know which controller is responsible for handling the form submit for attribute options?

Comment: No, sorry. But check the form's action tag and guess the controller from there

Comment: When I have had to do something similar I got lazy and simply made it part of the "admin" value of the attribute option, with a known separator. "ID Label Name" or "Label Name [ID]"

Comment: @iphigenie I thought about that too  adding it in admin value like __ID__LABEL NAME. But in the end decided to create a custom table to store the relation during sync

Comment: I noticed that magento 2 doesn't have any interface or real repository for attribute options so this makes things much harder. Moreover it doesn't seem to support extension attributes either to extend it. Basically the whole documentation for Magento 2 is pointless regarding attribute options. The only way to manage them is through the `AttributeOptionManagementInterface` which allows you to add and remove but not much else. I therefore decided to start an issue on github about this so that they can improve this at the very least. It seems magento relies a lot on legacy code still.